# Apply Fourier transform to the equation $\nabla\cdot[\mathbf{F}\delta(\mathbf{r})]=\nabla^2p$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

Consider an equation

$$\nabla\cdot[\mathbf{F}\delta(\mathbf{r})]=\nabla^2p,$$

in which $\mathbf{F}$ is a differentiable vector function, $\delta(\mathbf{r})$ is the Dirac delta function, $\nabla\cdot$ is a divergence operator, $\nabla^2$ is the Laplace operator, and $p$ is a differentiable scalar function.

I have difficult to apply Fourier transform to this equation in order to get $\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{F}=k^2\hat{p}$, where $\hat{}$ denotes the transformed function.

What I have tried is as follows:

$$\mathcal{F} [\mathrm{LHS}]=\mathcal{F}[(\nabla\delta)\cdot \mathbf{F}+\delta\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}]=\mathcal{F}[(\nabla\delta)\cdot \mathbf{F}]+\delta \mathcal{F}[\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}],$$

$$\mathcal{F}[\mathrm{RHS}]=[(\mathrm{i}k_x)^2+(\mathrm{i}k_x)^2]\hat{p}=-(k_x^2+k_y^2)\hat{p}\equiv-k^2\hat{p}.$$

I don't know how to further evaluate the FT of the LHS. Thank you in advance.

---

**Update** (Aug.24,2020):

Applying the definition of FT: $\hat{f}(\mathbf{k})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\mathbf{r})e^{-\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\:\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$

on LHS and RHS, respectively:

$$\mathcal{F}\{\nabla\cdot [\mathbf{F}\delta(\mathbf{r})]\}=\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathcal{F}[\mathbf{F}\delta(\mathbf{r})]=\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbf{F}\delta(\mathbf{r})e^{-\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\:\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k}\cdot\left(\mathbf{F}e^{-\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} \right)\vert_{\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{0}}=\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{0}),$$

and

$$\mathcal{F}[\nabla^2p]=(\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k})\cdot(\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k})\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p e^{-\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\:\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=-k^2\hat{p}.$$

It follows that $\mathrm{i}\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{0})=-k^2\hat{p}$, which differs from the expected result by a negative sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{\nabla \cdot (\vec F\delta)\}&=\mathscr{F}\{i\vec k\cdot \vec F\delta\}\\\\
&=i\vec k\cdot \vec F(0)
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, note that

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{\nabla \cdot (\vec F\delta)\}&=\mathscr{F}\{\vec F\cdot \nabla (\delta)+\delta \nabla\cdot \vec F\}\\\\
&=-\left.\left(\nabla \cdot (e^{-i\vec k\cdot \vec r}\vec F(\vec r))\right)\right|_{\vec r=0}+\left.\left(\nabla \cdot (\vec F(\vec r))\right)\right|_{\vec r=0}\\\\
&=i\vec k\cdot \vec F(0)
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: thank you for the answer. Could you give a little more details of the FT including $\delta$ function in any of your approaches? Please see my updated derivation using the definition of FT. Am I doing wrong somewhere?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Our answers differ because of our different definitions of the Fourier Transform.  I used the $e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec r}$ while you used $e^{-i\vec k \cdot \vec r}$.  So just replace $i$ with $-i$ and our answers are the same.

Comment: could you review my update. I understand what you were talking about. However, there is still a difference in the sign. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I did review you update and it is correct.  Again the reason our answers differ by a factor of $-1$ is that we are using different conventions for defining the Fourier Transform.  You're using the kernel $e^{-i \vec k \cdot \vec r}$ while I'm using the kernel $e^{+i \vec k \cdot \vec r}$.

Comment: I guess that I am doing wrong somewhere because my derivation is still different from the expected result by a sign even I stick to one convention. I have upvoted your answer and would accept one when the problem is solved.

Comment: What do you mean by "the expected result?"  Are you sure that you are using the same convention for defining the Fourier Transform.  If $\mathscr{F}\{G\}(\vec k)=\iiint_{-\infty}^\infty g(\vec r) e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec r}\,dx\,dy\,dz$, then that would explain the sign error.

Comment: please see line 5 and the last line of my post. Yes, I am using the same convection.

Comment: You're answer appears correct.